# How to temporarily block out light in this space on a budget

Tags: light

My friend is doing an art installation in one of these divided studio spaces:
[image: studio space photo]
(This is an example of those spaces - they are all similar to this, inside of a big open area and separated by divides)

She wants to block out the light to create a dark environment.

Some key points for the project

1. As the show is temporary, the solution needs to be temporary and removable after the show
2. Drilling on the divide is okay, but it’s not okay on the actual architecture of the building
3. The solution needs to look tidy and non-intrusive
4. Preferably using cheap materials as it’s a student project

Please share your expertise, thank you so much!

Comment: Fire code is **very** likely to be a problem. Check with the life safety folks responsible for the building (should be easy to find if student implies that this might be a college/university campus building.) Work with them, because trying to work around or against them doesn't work. A box of cheap sunglasses at the entrance, perhaps...

Answer (score 3):

Don't.

There is a reason those divided spaces don't have ceilings.  Because then each space needs it's own smoke detectors, fire sprinklers, etc.   If this is a public space with visitors crowding in and out you need to uphold the highest possible safety standards.   Building rooms out of flammable materials and blocking the fire safety systems is a bad idea.  Even if the fire safety authorities and the landlord allow it, it's a bad idea.

If you need a dark space go somewhere else.

Don't be the next night club fire disaster!  This is *exactly* how they all happen.   The artist puts up some fabric and it all goes downhill from there.

Answer (score 1):

Black cloth and some ties.

Use the air pipe as a means of getting the height or use rods across the divider walls. Depends on what headroom you want.

Choice of cloth will make a difference for the mass to be dealt with, too light ie thin and light will get through...

Jay613 made a good point about fire sprinklers etc... Do check.

Comment: And even use a pulley on the rod, so the 'curtain' can be lifted/dropped at will.

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel I have enough information to advise on specifics, but in general:

If this is an official gallery space, actually, your first step should be to work with whoever manages that space. They may have their own resources/rules to help with the project. Possibly even a budget that could be tapped.

Definitely ask the school safety office or equivalent. If they're like those at my alma mater, they will probably be delighted when someone asks first rather than their having to tell people to undo/redo work later.

How far would simply turning off lights/removing bulbs/covering windows get you? Could you perhaps extend the partition walls upward rather than trying to build a ceiling? Those might include baffled air vents, which might get you out of needing separate smoke detection or having to make other provisions for HVAC.

I presume you will have some sort of light trap at the entrance. Curtain,  black-painted entryway barrier, something of that sort. Note that this too must pass fire safety rules, and may require mounting temporary exit signs. For that matter, you may need to mount temporary emergency lighting. Again, this is all easier and cheaper if you can borrow equipment (and an electrician's help) from the school/site.